# What is the particular solution to $ \frac{dy}{dx} =\cos(x^2)$ with the initial condition $y\left( \sqrt {\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=3$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What is the particular solution to $ \frac{dy}{dx} =\cos(x^2)$ with the initial condition $y\left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=3$?

A.) $y = 3 + \int_{0}^{x}\cos(t^2)dt$

B.) $y = 3 + \int_{\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2}}^{x}\cos(t^2)dt$

C.) $y=  \frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x} + 3 - \frac{1}{2\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2}}$

D.) $y= \sin(x^2) + 2 $

So, I thought that the answer was D, as that looks like the derivative of that will be the equation that's given in the question. That's not correct though, and the integral of $\cos x^2$ looks like it should be sin$x^2$, but as said, D is not correct. Very confused on what to do.

Comment: You should have checked your answer by differentiation. It’s a moderately deep theorem that $\int\cos(x^2)dx$ can not be expressed as a nice formula in the familiar functions of Calculus. You have to fall back on the Fundamental Theorem. Which of the first three is correct?

Comment: Well, I think it's either A or B, as those differentiated are equal to cos$x^2$ and plugging in the square root of pi/2, they both equal 3. But only one can be correct, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Try differentiating, using the Fundamental Theorem

Comment: Hi @Ayanoria You've used the Multivariable-calculus tag twice in your last two posts when such a tag was not appropriate. Which I've now fixed for you. Please make sure to read what the tag means and try to use the correct tag(s) in the future :) Putting the good tags makes getting an (appropriate) answer more likely ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each proposed solution we need to check if $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x^2)$ and $y\left(\sqrt \frac \pi 2 \right) = 3$. The fundamental theorem of calculus will come in handy !

Let $x_0 = \sqrt \frac \pi 2$

You stated in the comments that you hesitated between $A$ and $B$.

For $A$ we have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 + \cos(x^2), \quad y(x_0) = 3 + \int_0^{\sqrt \frac \pi 2} \;\cos(t^2) dt.$$

Since $\cos(t^2) > 0$ on $\left(0,\sqrt \frac \pi 2 \right)$ we have

$$ y(x_0) = 3 + \int_0^{\sqrt \frac \pi 2} \;\cos(t^2) \; dt  > 3$$

This means that $y(x_0) \neq 3$ and that $A$ is not the correct choice.

For $B$ we have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 + \cos(x^2), \quad y(x_0) = 3 + \int_{\sqrt \frac \pi 2}^{\sqrt \frac \pi 2} \;\cos(t^2) dt = 3.$$

So $B$ is what you're looking for. There are no other correct choices since $C$ and $D$ don't verify $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x^2).$

Finally you say that the integral of $\cos(x^2)$ should be $\sin(x^2)$ this is not the case. This is a big mistake. It looks like you're doing something like this in your head :

"Let $u = x^2$ then the integral of $\cos(x^2)$ is the integral of $\cos(u)$ which is $\sin(u)$. Replace $u = x^2$ and the integral of $\cos(x^2)$ is $\sin(x^2)$ !  "

This is false !!! Why ? By the the same reasoning you could say that the integral of $\cos(g(x))$ is $\sin(g(x))$ but by the chain rule

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin(g(x)) = \cos(g(x)) g'(x) \neq \cos(g(x))$$

Comment: oh my god I love this answer!!! It literally explains everything! thank you so much!

Comment: @Ayanoria Glad I could help. I noticed I made a few typo's by writting $\cos^2(x)$ or $\cos(x)^2$ instead of $\cos(x^2)$. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a outline about it problem.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x^2) \implies y=\int \cos(x^2)dx +K$$
But we know that $$\int \cos(x^2)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x\right)+K$$ where $C(x)$ is the Fresnel $C$ integral.
Also we know that $y\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=3$, so $$K=3- 
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=3-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\cos \left( \frac{\pi x^{2}}{2}\right) dx$$
Finally $$\boxed{y=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x\right)+3-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\cos \left( \frac{\pi x^{2}}{2}\right) dx}$$I'll finish the details and the final answer later.